# How do I allow sprite images to remain the same when uploading in my memory card game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a memory card game in Unity2d. Basically the user will have to get a total of 8 matches in order for them to win the game. I have the game fully functional and I am trying to make it dynamic. I am able to upload my own images and load it into the game. However, the images in the game is not resized properly.

Here is the image when I upload into the game.

[image]

This is the picture that I wanted

[image]

The code I used for upload is

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using SFB;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenFileHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<Texture2D> LoadImage()
    {
        var extensions = new[] {
            new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "png", "jpg", "jpeg" )
        };

        var paths = StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel("Select Images", "", extensions, true);//StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel("Select Images", "", extensions, true);
        //System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Settings.txt")
        var textureList = new List<Texture2D>();

        foreach (var path in paths)
        {

            byte[] imageByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

            Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
            texture.LoadImage(imageByte);

            textureList.Add(texture);
        }
        //textureList.Resize(60, 60);
        //textureList.Apply();


        return textureList;
    }
}
```

I used a custom packed created by this dude in GitHub:
https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser

And the code that I used to change image into sprite is below:

```
.
.
.
    public List<Texture2D> textures;
.
.
    private float width;
    private float height;
.
.
void initializeCards()
    {
        OpenFile();

        .
        .
 
    }
.
.
public void OpenFile()
    {
        textures = OpenFileHelper.LoadImage();
        if (!_init)
        {
            _init = true;
        }
}
.
.
    public Sprite getCardFace(int i)
    {
        width = 101;
        height = 180;
        
        Sprite sp = Sprite.Create(textures[i - 1], new Rect(0, 0, width, height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f), 1.0f);
        return sp;
        
    }
```

I tried to do `textures.width` and `textures.height` in my Sprite.Create code. However, when I use those, I will get CS1061 error.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `textures` is a **[`List<Texture2D>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1)** of multiple `Texture2D` and indeed has no `width` or `height`. But a single [`Texture2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html) has ;)

You should probably use

```
public Sprite getCardFace(int i)
{
    var tex = textures[i - 1];
    var sp = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f, 1.0f);
    return sp;
}
```

Comment: O Thank you @derHugo
This works like a charm